# Undefined index in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Good day!

I am having the following error in my code:

```
<?php
if (!$_POST['SUBMIT']){   //ERROR: Undefined index
?>
    <H2>Add Employee</H2>
    <form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
       <tr>
            <td width="100">SSN</td>
            <td><input name="SSN" type="text" id="SSN"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" id="ADD" value="ADD"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
 <?php
    }
    else {
    //code here
    }
?>
```

How can I remove the error above? Thank you.

Comment: try and do a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` and see what's in the array first

Comment: Try using `isset()` and `!empty` instead of `!$_POST`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be a notice and not an error.

To fix is you'll have to check whether `$_POST['submit']` is set:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's where you test to see that is isn't there. It should be `!isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])`. This is because the index, `SUBMIT`, won't be set, thus won't have a value such as true to pass the `if(...)`. `isset()` checks to see if the index/variable is actually set.

Try this:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])){   //ERROR: Undefined index
?>
<H2>Add Employee</H2>
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
   <tr>
        <td width="100">SSN</td>
        <td><input name="SSN" type="text" id="SSN"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" id="ADD" value="ADD"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else {
    //code here
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])){   //ERROR: Undefined index
?>
```

This tests, if the index is set

Answer (score 3):

Options:

- Disable warning messages, by editing the setting in PHP.ini
- Add an `@` sign in front of the variable name, which will suppress the error on that particular line.
- Change your code to use `isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])` before checking it further.

Of these, the third option is definitely the best. You shouldn't assume that any variable supplied by the user will be set as you expect; you should always check that it's set at all, and also that it's set to the expected values. Otherwise you are liable to be open to hacking attacks.

Comment: The first two bullet points you suggest are bad practice and I wouldn’t recommend. The only time you want to disable warnings are when you run on production. Never use @, ever. There’s always a better alternative.

Comment: @Ollie - Granted I stated that the options are available, but I didn't recommend them; I explicitly stated that the `isset()` option was the one to go for.