# Notice: Undefined index: submit in sample.php on line 25

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

When do we get this error?

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\sample.php on line 25

What is the exact meaning of this perticular error?

Comment: Show me the code and then I will tell you!

Comment: Some code examples would be good. Take a look at how other people ask questions. Maybe even search for your question first, rather than answer it.

Comment: i am sorry... wait i am giving the code...

Comment: @sayantan bagchi: it's not necessary. There are 4 answers here and billion similar questions in the right "Related" bar

Comment: You are giving the error, which is why you have four answers which are correct. But you aren't giving your actual code that is generating the error. If you had given that, one of the four answers probably would have told you exactly what was wrong in the code and not all been generalized solutions. Also, being snappy when asking a question isn't really courteous or likely to result in getting more help.

Comment: @zerkms How has this not been closed as a duplicate yet?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I decided to get some easy rep points instead ;-P

Comment: @zerkms When you have 54.2k does an extra 20 really make that much of a difference? :-P

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: it was 54.1k before, so... yes ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Pssh! SO rounds up. You *only* have 54,157!

Comment: @zerkms Hey, don't be a greedy guts! Leave the easy rep for novices like myself so that we too can feel like we are contributing something to SO. You concentrate on this big tricky questions! :)

Comment: Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly

Comment: this is what i am getting whn i am trying to post the code

Comment: CAN I freshly post it once again whole code?

Comment: many many thanks to all of you... i have fixed the code... it works fine with google chrome... there is some prob with IE7... thank you guyess... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This means exactly what it says: you're addressing to an undefined index in an array

```
$arr = array();
echo $arr['foo'];
```

In the example above the array is empty but I tried to output `'foo'` item value, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It means you are trying to access a part of an arraythat isn't there.

If you have an array with 5 elements, you ca get to them via:

`$array[0]` through to `$array[4]`

But if you try `$array[76]` which doesn't exist, you will get an *undefined Index* error.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got an array that you're accessing like `$_POST['submit']`. That error message is saying is the element 'submit' of the array doesn't exist, and it's throwing a warning.

You should check that array elements exist before using them `isset()` before you access them to avoid avoid the warning.

Edit: possible duplicate of this: [Undefined index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676945/undefined-index-in-php)

Comment: i read that post... and i tried that bt its not helping that is why i have post mentioning this particular error...

Comment: @sayantan bagchi: what if you read some manual? http://php.net/isset

Comment: It's a standard PHP error. You're probably wondering why your form isn't submitting correctly, which is a different issue.

Comment: tahnk you so much... i will look into this...

Answer (score 0):

have you correctly mentioned the method in your form `GET` or `POST` ?? I think you are accessing/testing it without declaring it. Let me know if this is the case.