# Undefined index in PHP errors

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)
>   [Undefined index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676945/undefined-index-in-php)

> Notice: Undefined index: NAME in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmsx\lib\config.php on line 107

That's the exact error. Here's my code on the file. Thanks for those will help.

here's my line 107:

```
//echo "<br>" . $cdata;
// create the proper tree node if NAME attribute is set
if ($this->attr["NAME"] != "")
    $this->tags[count($this->tags) - 1] = $this->attr["NAME"];
```

[Pastie link](http://pastie.org/5439059)

Comment: exactly what does this have to with sql at all? sounds more like a DOM operation. did you check if the node you're on HAS a `NAME` attribute?

Comment: Can you give the output of `var_dump($this->attr);` ?

Comment: fwiw, your second line can be simplified `$this->tags[] = $this->attr["name"];`

Comment: @ScottEvernden, for what I can tell, the original line overwrites the last element, whereas yours adds. Though, it looks like the original line just has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/isset) first, to check, whether the property exists at all.

```
if ( isset( $this->attr["NAME"] ) && ($this->attr["NAME"] != "") ) {
    $this->tags[count($this->tags) - 1] = $this->attr["NAME"];
}
```

You error says, that the property `NAME` does not exist at all in the array `attr`!

Answer (score 0):

`NAME` isn't a defined index. You probably want:

```
if( isset($this->attr['NAME']) && $this->attr['NAME'] != "" ) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Funny. The post is edited by `ComFreek`. Are you related? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is `!empty($this->attr['NAME'])` instead of `$this->attr["NAME"]!=""`. Otherwise it errors out when NAME index is… well… undefined.